# Json Deserialize Object crashing

Tags: c#, .net, json, json.net

I'm trying to deserialize this JSON file into an object, but I can't get it working.

The Json:

```
"hotkeySets": {
     "Player 1": {
          "chatOff": [
                    {
                    "actionsetting": {
                            "action": "Togglelist"
                        },
                        "keysequence": "Ctrl+B"
                    },
                    {
                        "actionsetting": {
                            "action": "Copy"
                        },
                        "keysequence": "Ctrl+C"
                    },
                    {
                        "actionsetting": {
                            "useObject": 3308,
                            "useType": "SelectUseTarget"
                        },
                        "keysequence": "F10"
                    },
                ],
                "chatOn": [
                    {
                        "actionsetting": {
                            "action": "Select All"
                        },
                        "keysequence": "Ctrl+A"
                    },
                    {
                        "actionsetting": {
                            "chatText": "heal friend",
                            "sendAutomatically": true
                        },
                        "keysequence": "Ctrl+F1"
                    },
                    {
                        "actionsetting": {
                            "action": "Copy"
                        },
                        "keysequence": "Ctrl+C"
                    },
                ]
            },
            "Player 2": {
                "chatOff": [
                    {
                        "actionsetting": {
                            "action": "ToggleBattlelist"
                        },
                        "keysequence": "Ctrl+B"
                    },
                    {
                        "actionsetting": {
                            "action": "Copy"
                        },
                        "keysequence": "Ctrl+C"
                    },
            }
}
```

And here is the code I'm using to deserialize it:

```
JToken hotkeyConfig = JObject.Parse(json)
JToken hotkeysSet = hotkeyConfig.SelectToken("hotkeySets");

var sets = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, JObject>>(hotkeysSet.ToString());

foreach (var hotkeySet in sets) {
    string hotkeySetName = hotkeySet.Key; // "Player 1" etc..
    List<Hotkey> hotkeys = new List<Hotkey>();

    foreach (var hotkey in hotkeySet.Value) {

        Hotkey htk = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Hotkey>(hotkey.Value.ToString());    
     }
 }
```

But I can get the Hotkey object to work with Json Deserialize. I have tried a lot of things and here is the last code I tried:

```
public class Hotkey {

        [JsonProperty("actionsetting")]
        public ActionSetting actionsetting;

        [JsonProperty("keysequence")]
        public string Shortcut { get; set; }

        public class ActionSetting {
            public int useObject{ get; set; }

            public string chatText { get; set; }

            public string useType{ get; set; }

            public bool sendAutomatically{ get; set; }
        }
    }
```

It's crashing in the line "JsonConvert.DeserializeObject", saying invalid format, so probably I'm missing something in my class structure I guess.

Comment: Your code does not compile. What is hotkeyConfig?
Just by reading your code, something is wrong? Why do you call deserialize object so many times while you have just one JSON file? A single call to deserialize should be able to get you the whole object graph.

Comment: It is just the Json.Parse(), it's called "multiple" times, because the keys "Player 1", "Player 2", etc, they are all dynamic, so not necessarily they will get those names, it might be any name, and the Dictionary deserialize was the way I found to get that name(working), but when I try to deserialize the Value it crashs

Comment: Can you just get us a repro that can compile and run?

Comment: It seems that you are missing `action` property on `ActionSetting` class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, there is an error in your Json file. You are not closing the "chatOff" array of "Player 2". Check it below, where I closed it on the line before the last one:

```
"Player 2": {
    "chatOff": [
        {
            "actionsetting": {
                "action": "ToggleBattlelist"
            },
            "keysequence": "Ctrl+B"
        },
        {
            "actionsetting": {
                "action": "Copy"
            },
            "keysequence": "Ctrl+C"
        },
    ]
}
```

Second, your approach to map into Hotkey is fine, but you can not map your array items directly into the Hotkey class. As an alternative, you can map a new object to represent your Player, and then map the properties "chatOff" and "chatOn" into lists. Make your Json classes look like this:

```
public class Player
{
    [JsonProperty("chatOff")]
    public List<Hotkey> ChatOff { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("chatOn")]
    public List<Hotkey> ChatOn { get; set; }
}

public class Hotkey
{
    [JsonProperty("actionsetting")]
    public ActionSetting ActionSetting;

    [JsonProperty("keysequence")]
    public string Shortcut { get; set; }
}

public class ActionSetting
{
    [JsonProperty("useObject")]
    public int UseObject { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("chatText")]
    public string ChatText { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("useType")]
    public string UseType { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("sendAutomatically")]
    public bool SendAutomatically { get; set; }
}
```

Last, make your deserializing code look like this:

```
var hotkeyConfig = JObject.Parse(json);

var playersToken = hotkeyConfig.SelectToken("hotkeySets");

var playersDictionary = 
    JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, JObject>>(
        playersToken.ToString());

foreach (var playerEntry in playersDictionary)
{
    var player = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Player>(playerEntry.Value.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Just an FYI, but you do not need all those `JsonProperty` attributes. JSON.NET will map the camelCase names in the JSON to the PascalCase names in the .NET class as long as the names match case-insensitively. The only time you need the `JsonProperty` is if the names do not match. They just create "noise" otherwise.

Comment: Sure, @CraigW. I do it mostly to simplify things in case Cartel wanted to change property names.

Answer (score 0):

Check your Json string, the format is bad how the error show you. Here i let you the correct format for the Json string you posted.

```
{
"hotkeySets": {
    "Player 1": {
        "chatOff": [{
            "actionsetting": {
                "action": "Togglelist"
            },
            "keysequence": "Ctrl+B"
        }, {
            "actionsetting": {
                "action": "Copy"
            },
            "keysequence": "Ctrl+C"
        }, {
            "actionsetting": {
                "useObject": 3308,
                "useType": "SelectUseTarget"
            },
            "keysequence": "F10"
        }],
        "chatOn": [{
            "actionsetting": {
                "action": "Select All"
            },
            "keysequence": "Ctrl+A"
        }, {
            "actionsetting": {
                "chatText": "heal friend",
                "sendAutomatically": true
            },
            "keysequence": "Ctrl+F1"
        }, {
            "actionsetting": {
                "action": "Copy"
            },
            "keysequence": "Ctrl+C"
        }]
    },
    "Player 2": {
        "chatOff": [{
            "actionsetting": {
                "action": "ToggleBattlelist"
            },
            "keysequence": "Ctrl+B"
        }, {
            "actionsetting": {
                "action": "Copy"
            },
            "keysequence": "Ctrl+C"
        }]
    }
}
}
```

here is a Json validator where you can test it [JsonValidator](http://jsonlint.com/)
I hope this solves your problem.